# Changing Language of PayPal payment gateway

Tags: ecommerce, paypal, payments, payment-gateway

I am creating a German version of a web store that is built in OpenCart.  I have everything translated from English to German, although I just need to switch the PayPal payment gateway to a German version.  I'm not sure the best way of going about this.

I've done lots of looking on Google but haven't found any information.  I've also tried to post on the OpenCart community forums without success.

The payments would be going to the same account as the English website, I just need to change the PayPal interface to German.

Comment: Have you asked PayPal? You can call them and get the answer I am sure.

Comment: Solved it, there is a controller inside OpenCart that sends all the parameters to PayPal.  It has 'EN' hardcoded in for the Locale, just had to change that to 'DE'.

Comment: Congratulations! Why don't you write an answer and I can up-vote it for you.

Comment: BTW- Welcome to the site. It is quiet now, but we do have some real experts here that can often help. SEO tends to the be hot topic these days.

Answer (score 1):

Originally posted as a comment by [Curtis Fleming](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/46752/curtis-fleming):

> There is a controller inside OpenCart that sends all the parameters to PayPal. It has 'EN' hardcoded in for the Locale, just had to change that to 'DE'.